# How to deploy my samrt contract on testnet in EOS

Tags: eosjs, eosio-code, testnet

I have successfully pushed the transaction and deployed the smart contract on private net, I want to know How to deploy it on testnet.

I have created the account on Jungle testnet.. Kindly tell me the further process